# Burninate [custom-lists]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

[custom-lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-lists)

- 300 questions about various list type things, mainly by low rep
  users.
- 3 followers (not clear what they're actually following)
- No wiki

Questions on subjects ranging from [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/list), [expandablelistview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expandablelistview) to well basically anything with the name list in it.

Many of the highest voted ones appear to be talking about a "*custom list view*" in android. Not an android dev so unclear if this is a thing or not. But it certainly appears to have a different name...

Comment: The is a [tag:listview] that looks like good candidate for re-tagging for all of the questions using custom-list as a custom-list-view.

Comment: Thanks for posting this burnination request and allowing the community to take a close look at it. Please note that burninations are not just tag removals - They are the process of carefully moderating a specific place of Stack Overflow. Avoid only mass-editing the tag out of questions as it is counter-productive. Flag/vote/edit/retag the posts after consensus is reached. For more info, see [Shog9's answer on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/306392) or the [unofficial SOCVR process](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation/blob/master/burnination.md#process).

Comment: I can't find anything on these [custom-lists]