# Evaluation of SOCVR's Burnination Process

Tags: discussion, burninate-system

> **Attention**
>
> if you're looking for the official process please see the FAQ post: [What is the process for tag removal (burnination)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination?noredirect=1&lq=1)
> All what you read here is captured, extended, improved and maintained there.
>
> This question and its answers are left here for historical reference and will be part of my memoirs in 6 to 8 weeks.

---

In the last couple of months, the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room implemented
the [burnination process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307124/578411) previously proposed by [Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9). As a room owner, I took the liberty to fork that [process on GitHub](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation/blob/master/burnination.md)
so we could adapt and adjust quickly without risking the hate/love of Meta for every bump of a meta post.

To be clear: approval from Shog9 was obtained [here](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4541030#4541030) and moderator support from Madara Uchiha was also obtained  [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/28601178#28601178).

This question is meant as an evaluation of the process as executed over the first 5 tags handled by the SOCVR room, as well as our handling of new burnination requests.

#### The slightly adapted process

1. When a [burninate-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/burninate-request) is posted, it will be marked [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) until/unless it scores at least 20.
   If it never achieves this score, then it should not be acted on; don't interpret apathy as a sign of support.

> Note that 1. wasn't executed during the test. We implemented a less invasive option by leaving a comment on the post ([like this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323081/ive-done-some-research-and-i-found-a-tag-that-needs-to-go#comment344431_323081)). We still feel this re-tag is needed for new requests.

2. After reaching the threshold score, the request will be [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) for one day,
   exposing it to as much attention on Stack Overflow as possible.

- Any [punny titles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295583/why-do-people-have-a-little-pun-with-their-retag-and-burninate-requests) will be replaced with, "*Should we burninate [name of tag]?*"
- The following [hidden warning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317046/578411) and public notice will be added to the top of the post:

  ```
  <!--
    MODERATOR NOTE TO EDITORS:
    Please don't edit post title while it has featured tag.
    If you ignore this note, it will be considered as abuse and handled accordingly.
  -->
  ```

  ```
  *This tag is in phase 2 of the burnination process described [here](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation/blob/master/burnination.md).
  ```

The question and comments have been cleaned to allow for on-topic discussion on this tag,
please keep it that way. If you want to discuss the process itself, visit the
[SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room.*

- The question will get a post notice: Featured Burninate Request

```
 This will be a chance for folks to show their support *and* a chance for folks who thought it was too silly to be worth talking about to step up and explain why the request should be denied.
```

3. After its day in the spotlight, a moderator, or someone else on the Community Team
   will review the request and any arguments against it.
   [There are four criteria for burnination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191) - if the tag doesn't meet all<sup>1</sup> of them, **or if it is clear that removing it will do more harm than good**, the request will be declined. I'd have preferred to run this process purely on voting, but... That would inevitably lead to trouble. [Your distaste for a frustrating game shouldn't result in the destruction of otherwise-valid tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273079/we-have-a-flappy-bird-clone-tag-really).
   A high influx of down votes or fresh comments during its featured phase is a signal to hold back on burnination.
4. If the tag can be cleanly removed at this point, the moderator skips directly to step #6.
   If it requires further disambiguation, the request will be tagged [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) signalling that it is
   time for widespread review and revision of the questions in the tag.
   [This is the time to clean up the edges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191).
   **During this time, the tag will be blocked with a message that links back to the request meta post.**.
   The SOCVR room will be heading the effort.
5. When Step #4 is completed, whoever is spearheading this request will flag it for moderator attention and the moderator proceed to step #6.
6. A moderator will ping a CM to delete any closed, downvoted questions in the tag and remove it from the system entirely. This assumes the tag wasn't already removed during review in Step #4.

#### Tags that were burninated under this process

- [once](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258571/burninate-once) (burninated)
- [corners](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295233/should-we-throw-corners-in-the-corner) (burninated)
- [close](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308117/lets-close-close-249-qs) (burninated)
- [guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298984/we-dont-need-guidelines) (burninated)
- [priority](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285084/burninate-priority) (burninated)

#### Our approach

When the burninate request gets ‘approved’, we post an answer describing the actions we expect from those that are participating, for example [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319601/578411). In the chat room we put the tag on our star-board and during our close vote events the specific tag is suggested as a filter option. Users that are editing seek advice in the chatroom for specific posts. On a daily basis the progress statistics are updated.

#### Some recent questions on which we left comments

[Can we relay the [facebook-relay] tag to [relayjs]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322982/can-we-relay-the-facebook-relay-tag-to-relayjs#comment343780_322982)
[Can we start burninating or synonymising [initalization]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322823/can-we-start-burninating-or-synonymising-initalization#comment342924_322823)
[Burninate [custom-lists]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322308/burninate-custom-lists#comment340224_322308)

#### Next steps

After carefully evaluating the feedback, <s>I'll create a [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) meta post so that the process can be maintained on Meta.</s> the SOCVR RO team has created a faq-proposed post covering the process [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-burninating-tags). That implements the request made earlier by [Martin Smith](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319914/automatically-append-guidance-to-questions-tagged-burninate-request).

#### Possible concerns to be addressed by the community, moderators and SO staff

[SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) is an activist room that makes an impact in moderation on the main Q&A site.

- Is its effect regarding burnination noticed, appreciated, and warranted?
- Should chat rooms be involved in burnination requests?
- Should burnination requests be orchestrated at all?
- Is the moderator team equipped to handle any extra workload caused by burninating?
- Is the CM team still OK with this process, its implications, and its goals?

On behalf of the SOCVR RO team and regulars, I'm looking forward to your valuable feedback.

<sup>1. [Meet All or any criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#comment896615_239191)</sup>

Comment: I didn't track all recent burnination requests in detail, but I saw at least once that a user started removing tags when the burnination progress entered step 2. I think there should be a clearly visible note, that "featured" doesn't mean that tags should already be removed. Apart from that: Good work!

Comment: @honk yeah, in a community moderated model I don't see much options to have a strict process on one side and have everybody stick to it on the other side. Unless you want to switch from janitors to armed forces...

Comment: Of course, if a user decides to ignore the process, then there is nothing you can do about. But for the rest, it should become obvious when it's about time to switch into berserk mode and start actual burnination. Otherwise, how about the idea to trade guns for badges? ;)

Comment: Will I get featured for [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323081)? My one suggestion on this process is to at least allow a pun as a bold subheading... (I'm very proud of my puns.)

Comment: @Laurel Agree :)

Comment: There are currently [448 uncompleted burnination requests](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=[burninate-request]%20-[status-completed]%20is%3aq), several with more than a 100 votes. Will the process apply to all requests, or only those made after a certain date?

Comment: I can imagine the status-review will only be applied to new questions and maybe other groups/rooms or even single users can take on a request. They can follow the process @Mogsdad

Comment: The sheer amount of work people put into this... Don't get me wrong, this is all very good stuff you are doing. But it is so much work! Why not deal with the root of the problem instead? Raise the rep bar needed to create tags to... 20k? Or preferably, block _all_ users from doing this, then implement a _tag creation process_, where any user can petition for a tag to be created. It feels like SO is working backwards with the way it handles tags.

Comment: @Lundin the problem is the existing tags, not the new ones.  It's reasonably easy to catch new tags and deal with them without this process.

Comment: @Lundin if I assume good faith, every tag starts as a good tag. Only time will learn if a tag is a crap magnet. In that sense it is good to have tags that attract posts with some common characteristics so you easy deal with the posts. That in the end the tag gets deleted as well is almost a side-effect.

Comment: Taking the puns out of burnination? Let's just take all the joy out of everything :(

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist only during the featured state, I'm sure you can live with one-day no fun, right?

Comment: @rene Only kidding. I only wish I were smart enough to have come up with a pun to insert into my complaint. :D

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Don't worry, it's not *pun*ishment

Comment: @Lundin 20k is *far* too high a barrier to create a new tag. As has been said already, the problem today is with existing tags that weren't policed in the past, not new tags.

Comment: I'm guessing that [meta-tag:status-declined] in step 3 and [meta-tag:status-completed] in step 6 go without saying?

Comment: @bergi it will be based on the evidence presented, so if there are objections a status-declined can be expected and if the progress answer has all counts on zero we flag for a moderator to re-tag. We didn't had a status-declined in the test but we did consult our regular mods before continuing.

Comment: Even if the post has 20 votes, it doesn't get [meta-tag:featured] anymore. I flagged for mod attention and got declined.

Comment: @S.S.Anne Yeah, I'm sorry SO Inc. made some decisions that took the heart out of this process. The mod in command is picking up some work but assured me they will not touch burninations until tooling on the mod-side is improved. We simply lack the CM capacity atm to be effective on huge effort burns. Please nibble at the smaller ones ...  and again appologies we can't get this on track any sooner.

Comment: @S.S.Anne I wasn't aware of this but it turns out mods rather not have flags on burnination request to feature them. It is buried in the [small print at the end](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356821/578411)

Answer (score 31):

> Is its effect regarding burnination noticed, appreciated and warranted?

We'll never get rid of *all* the bad tags, but every one that *is* gone makes a small difference. I appreciate people taking the time to help out with these kinds of things.

Of course it's warranted, bad tags should be removed (and bad posts closed along with them)

> Should chat rooms be involved in burnination requests?

Chat provides a convenient way to orchestrate these kinds of things. I don't see any reason they shouldn't be, and to my knowledge there hasn't been a practical example of abuse stemming from this.

> Should burnination requests be orchestrated at all?

Not sure how else they would be practical. Again, until there's a real abuse vector here, I don't have a problem with it.

> Is the moderator team equipped to handle any extra workload caused by burninating?

Can't speak for the others, but I'd say we are. Tagging these [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) is easy enough, and any flags are just icing on the already-huge flag cake. Also, flags generated by SOCVR people are *easy* to handle; you folks know what you're doing. Comment flags are fractions of a second each, and NAA/VLQ flags are quick, even if they don't get handled by the queue first.

Comment: There has been one known abuse from burninations: [Clean-up by downvoting? A ridiculous user experience](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307009/clean-up-by-downvoting-a-ridiculous-user-experience)

Answer (score 19):

When a tag has a small number of questions, this process is way over the top.   For example, why does it need 20 people to vote on removing a tag that is only used on 10 questions?

Therefore useless small tags just don't get cleaned up, or one person does them without admitting what they are doing on meta.

Comment: I agree on that. Do you have some rule of thumb to distinguish between *go ahead on your own* requests and *needs orchestration with more hands on deck*  requests? Is it just the number of questions in a tag or also some quality attributes?

Comment: @rene, It can’t just be number of questions as a tag created today may have 1 question…  Not having a tag wiki, clear misspelling of anther tag,  low number of followers, clear replacement tag(s) to use.

Comment: It does not have to be "go ahead on your own", it could be a much quicker process on meta.

Comment: I meant with my *go ahead on your own* that indeed no process was involved. So that might be a step 0 in the *process*: does the request need a process? if not -> it probably can be burninated within a day because of the criteria's you mentioned earlier.

Comment: Is your point similar to [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322335/do-i-need-to-ask-before-burninating-tiny-tags)?

Comment: Yes, part of the problem is that if anyone ask about removing any tag however few questions it has and clear cut the case is, they get people telling them to use the "approved process".   Therefore the "approved process" should have short cuts in it.

Comment: OK, I'll bring that to the final process, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: I think that what Ian means to say is that the process of removing tags is having way too much friction, meanwhile creation is just easy pie.

Comment: If you have time can you check if your concern is covered in [the burnination process](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/578411)? cc @Braiam

Comment: @rene,  how does someone ask on meta to confirm "There are four criteria for burnination - if the tag doesn't meet all of them" without then having to use the complete process?   It still seems to be "do it and tell no one" or use the complete process.

Comment: Hmm, it needs better wording, right? I'm not a native speaker but would a *confirmation/reassured* be a better fit? So I think I'm looking for a word that conveys *either your peers/ or your own best judgement concluded burnination can take place*. Should we maybe suggest that askers state their intent: I'm telling you I'm going to do this/I'm asking for some help/please organize this for me ...

Answer (score -15):

> Any [punny](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295583/1419007) titles will be replaced with, "*Should we burninate [name of tag]?*"

Unless the title is confusing or otherwise inappropriate, this seems superfluous. Puns [may help motivate more people to look at the proposal](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295586/1419007) and it's less fun if all burnination requests in "Hot Meta posts" share the same title.

Comment: "it's less fun...", but isn't that a good thing because [we hate fun](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/)?

Comment: The punny title remain while the request is a "Hot meta question".  It just gets replaced _after it gets enough upvotes to be featured_.  By this time, it has already gotten enough attention to be considered.

Comment: I think the notion of removing other peoples' content from the site warrants being given serious consideration. It's a small ask.

Comment: This was also discussed in [this other post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316947/keep-the-love-of-puns-burninating-in-our-hearts).

Comment: @zzzzBov, There's a kind of TL;DR at the bottom. *"On Stack Overflow, contrary to popular opinion, we don't hate fun. But only a certain amount of fun will be tolerated, and always with steely, businesslike frowns. :)"*

Comment: @ryanyuyu, Thanks for the clarification. *"The punny title remain while the request is a 'Hot meta question'."*

Comment: Almost every single burnination pun I've seen in the last year has been contrived and unfunny. The quicker they die the better imo.

Comment: @DavidG That's really a matter of a pinion.

Comment: @Draco18s An opinion that many people share, and from memory, one of those people was Shog9.

Comment: @DavidG Oh I know, I just like to tease people who don't like puns with puns. ;) I actually managed to teach someone who is a mutual friend with me and another friend who hates puns, how to pun. She hits me for his puns now too.