# Unmanageable [content-management-system]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

I think this tag falls into the same category as [api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api): it's just too nondescript to be useful.

[cms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cms) is usually used when:

- Asking us to recommend a CMS (off-topic)
- A specific CMS tag is lonely (unnecessary)
- When another tag should be made to describe an obscure CMS

  - These need new tags. I already created [pagekit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pagekit).
- Designing a CMS. I think that a new tag: [cms-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cms-design) (or similar) is in order.

  - This parallels [api-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api-design)

---

There are over 5k questions tagged with this, so it's practical, but large. While some of them might just need the tag removed, there are plenty that need to be closed/deleted for being blatant rule violations.

These questions, by my judgement, are some of the recent ones that need to be closed:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37607907
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37227844
- [Highly customizable/templatable CCK for Joomla 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37136710)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076583

Some others:

- [Drupal or from-scratch web app development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786712)
- [Extremely simple content updating tool for websites - CMS? PHP forms? Suggestions please!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418850)
- [Which CMS, if any, would be best suited for a database-driven website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806078)
- [Common features of a robust CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397529)
- [Content management system for graphics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399190)
- [CMS Trends - Custom Vs Prebuilt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545233)
- [Am I over-engineering (jumping the shark, so to speak) this app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933644)
- [.NET CMS to manage copy changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31532651)
- [What is the "best" free CMS for my needs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618685)
- [Which Open Source CMS do you find most reliable and performance-oriented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69832)

Even these highly up voted ones are off-topic:

- [How are people handling content management system production staging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535580)
- [Most Important Features for a CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380259)
- [Umbraco Yay or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699847)
- [Is there a point creating a site using XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560635)
- [Simple clean CMS for programming project website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087275)
- [Simple multilingual CMS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912944)
- [mojoPortal OR Umbraco?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901073)

Comment: Thanks for posting this request and allowing the community to weigh in! Please note that burninating a tag is the process of carefully moderating a specific piece of Stack Overflow (please think twice before doing tag-only mass edits, as they can be counter-productive); once the community reaches a consensus, burnination can proceed. For more info, see [Shog9's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/306392) on MSE or the [unofficial SOCVR process](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323121/4174897) on MSO.

Comment: Not downvoting but I was close.... Man... you have an opinion on every line in that description. Just take a step back and consider that each of those lines in the description actually make sense. You might not like it but hey... this is about programmers having problems and needing answers. Whether you don't sleep at night because there are multiple subcategories under a tag is fairly irrelevant to them. To them, it is all CMS anyway.

Comment: @WernerVanBelle The tag doesn't actually make it easier to find anything (except for off-topic questions). It fails to categorize things in a meaningful way, and it's abused. How does it help anyone find answers?

Comment: Personally I use Google to find things. Almost never the tags. But if someone would use the cms tag he will find that each post is indeed related to cms

Comment: @WernerVanBelle You could make the same argument for using the [code] tag. Indeed, the question will be about code, but it's not helpful as a way to categorize questions. From what I have seen so far, many questions use the CMS tag instead of specific tags, like the one that goes with the specific CMS.

Comment: @WernerVanBelle the main purpose of tags is to connect the people that have questions with those that can answer them, everything else is secondary. This tag fails at the most important one.