# A [custom] Burnination Request

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

Recently I got access to some moderation tools and today in the **New tags** section I noticed a [custom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom) tag.

It is a SO custom (tradition; usual or habitual practice; typical mode of behaviour) to create new tags. But I believe [custom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom) was a mistake or a typo. It seems to be too broad. There are 4 questions currently and there is [customization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/customization) with ~3000 usages which could be used as substitute if necessary.

So I vote to burn [custom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom) tag before it breeds.

---

[custom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom) temporarly reappeared on June 8

---

[custom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom) is back again on August 31. [One of the questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39242216/visual-composer-custom-markup-for-custom-shortcode-image-do-not-show-vc-map) has **only** the [custom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom) tag (even without a language tag).

Comment: It looks like it was burninated before. There's no way it got 30+ followers from 4 questions in 24 hours. Perhaps we should consider blacklisting it.

Comment: I notices it too my precious!

Comment: @pnuts, is it time to blacklist probably?

Comment: Both "custom" and "customization" are meta-tags, if you ask me.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

We really don't need a huge process to re-tag 4 questions.

Solved. Move on please, nothing to see here.

The tag will be removed at 03:00 UTC, when the clean-up script for orphaned tags runs.

Comment: Especially since what we can see is all blurry.

Comment: @Rene, tag *custom* itself: will it stay or be blacklisted or what ? ...

Comment: @ASh see my edit: at 03:00 UTC it will be removed

Comment: @rene, thanks! now I understand tags lifecycle much better. if I see a similar small unclear tag, should I bring it to Meta for discussion or remove it from questions myself and rely on cleanup script? also TylerH commented about 32 followers, so it is probably not the 1st time, when *custom* was added?

Comment: @Ash  It depends a bit. Some say if you're sane and feel confident you can happily retag on your own. I suggested to at least get someone else to verify the uselessness of the tag. The [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) is open for that. On the [evaluation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323290/578411) there was a suggestion to not have every burnination over regulated.

Comment: Hi! The tag 'custom' does not seem to have any questions tagged, but it does not appear removed to me. Is there something wrong? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom

Comment: @Alfro you get [that is a miss](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/anythingwillwork) for any tag doesn't exist so this is by design.

Comment: @rene not for this one, since the wiki message appears, unlike for actual misses. Also, 'custom' appears in the search: http://s33.postimg.org/pndeoyc73/custom_search.png

Comment: Hmm. maybe the tag cleanup script doesn't run ... no wait ... it has [one question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37738777/custom-qtproperty-with-qtpropertybrowser-and-custom-edit-widget) ... retagged and close voted ...