# Burninate [letter] tag

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

I came across [letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/letter) tag that should be burninated, because there's no sense in being an expert in letters. [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/letter) do not even seem like they're from the same category.

Comment: Thanks for posting this request and allowing the community to weigh in! Please note that burninating a tag is the process of carefully moderating a specific piece of Stack Overflow (please think twice before doing tag-only mass edits, as they can be counter-productive); once the community reaches a consensus, burnination can proceed. For more info, see [Shog9's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/306392) on MSE or the [unofficial SOCVR process](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323121/4174897) on MSO.

Comment: Oh, I didn't expect that Meta has a custom of giving an advise for burnination noobies. Thanks!

Comment: This [letter] will self destruct in five, four, three ...

Comment: Right. I suggest `Burn this [letter] after reading`.

Comment: That tag is so small and still manages to be all over the place.

Comment: **[♫ \[Letter\] Go ♫](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ginx7WKq5GE)**

Comment: PC UNLOAD [LETTER]

Comment: *because there's no sense in being an expert in letters* - I wish someone had told me this before I embarked upon a D.Litt. course.

Answer (score 23):

Most of these questions use [letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/letter) synonymously with [character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/character). One question surely means [typography](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typography) instead. Yet another question was vastly confused and used "letter" to mean *email*, but I ended up editing the entire question; it had nothing to do with email/letters at all, so I changed all the tags.

I also suggest that we look at [letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/letters). It has a little more tagged with it, but it is just as horrible, so it should go too. In total, there are [388 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/letter+or+letters) between the two.

I will see about going ahead and retagging some questions that certainly be tagged with a different, better tag.

I'd also like to point out that we may benefit from a new tag, [unicode-letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unicode-letter), which would be used for precisely one thing: the regex construct that matches letters (`\p{L}` in some flavors).

**Important notice:** I see someone created [letters-and-numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/letters-and-numbers), presumably to replace [letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/letter). **NO.** Please consult us before proposing a new tag to replace the one undergoing burnination. I would have told you that [alphanumeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alphanumeric) already exists if you had.

Comment: unsure about [tag:unicode-letter], otherwise agree. wouldn't that encourage also [tag:letter] coming back, and how would you deduct from tag name that it is about a regex construct?

Comment: You are forgetting [tag:character-encoding].

Comment: Next tag to burn: [character].

Comment: @Lundin And also [char].

Comment: I created [tag:letters-and-numbers]. Although there may be some overlap with [tag:alphanumeric], I think there's also enough distinction to warrant a different tag. I also created [tag:projects-and-solutions] long ago to fuse questions tagged with _projects_ with those tagged _solutions_ and that seemed to do well.

Comment: @MarkCidade Out of the 10 questions currently tagged [tag:letters-and-numbers], half of them seem to have nothing to do with the usages specified. Are you sure this is a good idea?

Comment: @beaker Converting between letters and numbers is one usage, the other simply being about letters and numbers in general (where they were originally tagged [tag:letters] and [tag:numbers]). I think that combining them into one tag is a good idea, but we can also separate the usages into the existing [tag:alphanumeric] and a _converting letters to/from numbers_ tag.

Comment: @MarkCidade You need to consider a bit more about how tags are used. Not all keywords should be tags, only those that provide meaningful classification. I think that existing tags, such as alphanumeric and cipher sufficiently cover either definition.

Comment: They don't cover everything. _Alphanumeric_ implies a string that has letters and digits. _Cipher_ implies encryption. Someone may ask a question that may very well be answered by mentioning alphanumeric strings or encryption ciphers, but they may also be asking for a regular expression, or some details about the Unicode standard without knowing it. All _they_ know is that is has something to do with _letters-and-numbers_ and together like that, it's not as ambiguous as either _letter_ or _number_, in the same way _projects-and-solutions_ makes sense but a _project_ or _solution_ is too vague.

Comment: @MarkCidade I don't see any situation in which I would search for that tag, follow it, or use it in any meaningful way. I don't want to highjack this question, but if you'd care to open a new discussion to present your case then we can see what others think about it. Otherwise, imo it's just more fuel for the burnination fire.

Comment: @MarkCidade I agree with beaker about *letters-and-numbers*. There are some things that don't make good tags. Otherwise we would have a *code* tag and it would be on 90% of the questions here.

Comment: _Code_ is too vague. [tag:code-and-cookies-and-cream] provides sufficient context. I don't expect _letters-and-numbers_ to be as successful as, say, [tag:projects-and-solutions] but it fills a niche.